# How to display count of records in view in asp.net MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi guyz I have this scenario.. I have a looped table of different class(Class Name) in my view... My problem is I want to count the number of students that are present and absent.. where am I suppose to have the counting? Is it in the view? cotroller? or model? and how am I going do that?   I'm quite new to this so please help me guyz.. Thanks in advance.. If you need more info please tell me..

```
Class Name: Star Class 
Class Adviser: James Anderson
 __________________
|  Students Status |
|__________________|
|Johny Jo | Absent |
|_________|________|
|Jenny Ye | Present|
|_________|________|

number of present: ?
number of absent: ?
```

Comment: Your best off doing this in the controller. What is the structure to all this though? String? or Array? etc

Comment: Im using string in my model..

Answer (score 3):

Do it in the Controller. Depending on how you have this modeled:

```
var count_present = db.YourModel
.Where(y => y.status.Equals("Present"))
.Count();
ViewBag.count_present = count_present;

var count_absent = db.YourModel
.Where(y => y.status.Equals("Absent"))
.Count();
ViewBag.count_absent = count_absent;
```

I'm using a ViewBag here to keep it simple, normally I'd use a View Model.

Comment: I suspect the last sentence is supposed to be ViewBag.count_absent = count_absent; instead of ViewBag.count_present = count_absent; ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like: `int presentCount = attendees.Count(a => a.Status == Attendance.Present)` in your controller. I'm not sure how you are storing the information, so I've just taken a punt that there is a collection of attendees that have some kind of flag to show the status.

Comment: +1 ok dude.. I'm gonna try that later when I go home.. :) thanks for the suggestion..